# PHP PDO - Retrieve the changed product

Tags: php, mysql, database

I made a system in PHP where I can change the value of a price from a product in a database. But when I try to receive the data from the product that was changed I get an error stating `Unknown column 'F0445' in 'where clause'`

I have no idea why this is happening? The code to change the selected product  is working perfectly fine but when I try to retrieve the product information from the product I've just changed it goes mayhem;

```
<?php
include "databaseconnectie4.php"
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$conn = getDatabaseConnection();
$query = "SELECT omschrijving,verkoopprijs,artikelnr FROM artikel";
?>

<h1>Prijs wijziging</h1>
<hr>
<p>Selecteer een artikel</p>
<form action="opdracht10.php" method="POST">
<select name="selectedOption" id="">
    <?php foreach($conn->query($query) as $result): ?>
        <option value="<?=$result['artikelnr'];?>"><?=$result['omschrijving'];?>, <?=$result['verkoopprijs'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<p>Geef de nieuwe prijs:</p>

<input type="number" name="newValue"><br>
<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Voer wijziging door!">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    changePrice($conn);
}

function changePrice($conn) {
   $price = $_POST['newValue'];
   $optionChosen = $_POST['selectedOption'];

   $data = [
    'price' => $price,
    'artikelnr' => $optionChosen,
   ];
   $sql = "UPDATE artikel SET verkoopprijs=:price WHERE artikelnr=:artikelnr";
   $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute($data);

   $selectChangedItem = "SELECT Artikelnr, omschrijving, verkoopprijs FROM artikel WHERE Artikelnr = $optionChosen";

   $conn->query($selectChangedItem);

   foreach($conn->query($selectChangedItem) as $result) {
    echo $result['Artikelnr'];

   }

}
```

The database setup for the table "Artikel" looks like this:

```
- Artikelnr (This is the product number)
- Omschrijving (Description)
- Categorie (Category)
- Verkoopprijs (Price)
```

What is causing this?

Comment: `... WHERE Artikelnr = $optionChosen` You should use a prepared statement here too. Both to avoid sql injection and because your value does not seem to be numeric.

Comment: I've tried it already but I retrieved the exact same error. I have no idea what to do. The value of $optionChosen is just the "Artikelnr" so I suppose `... WHERE Artikelnr = $optionChosen` should be correct and it should return the right results?

Comment: You *are* gonna get hacked if you don't use prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `$optionChosen` in quotes:

```
$selectChangedItem = "SELECT Artikelnr, omschrijving, verkoopprijs FROM artikel WHERE Artikelnr = '$optionChosen'";
```